# Can't concatenate Javascript and Struts tag

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts

I'm trying to create invisible divs with jQuery which in title will be populated dinamically by an struts tag, but its giving me invalid indexed property error:

```
 Invalid indexed property 'niveisRisco['+<%=ctr%>+']
```

Heres the code i'm using:

```
$(function(){
        var mapaAplicacaoJs = $('#MapaAplicacao area'); 
        var mapaPerfilJs = $('#MapaPerfil area');

       <logic:present name="carteiraSelecionada">
        <logic:iterate name="carteiraSelecionada" property="carteiraAtual.niveisRisco" id="foo" indexId="ctr">
            mapaAplicacaoJs.each(function() {  
                mapaAplicacaoJs.before('<div id="nivel_risco_dv" class="tabindex" title="<bean:write name="carteiraSelecionada" property="carteiraAtual.niveisRisco['+<%=ctr%>+'].getDescricao" />"></div>');
         </logic:iterate>
        </logic:present>        
        });
```

If i hardcode `<div id="nivel_risco_dv" class="tabindex" title="<bean:write name="carteiraSelecionada" property="carteiraAtual.niveisRisco[0].getDescricao` it works.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my concatenation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not attribute with name indexId in logic:iterate tag. See [logic:iterate](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-logic.html#iterate)
Access it with $ctr instead of doing it via scriplet